# How to get the attribute of clicked image from a list of images using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, attr

I have 5 images in a div

```
    <div class="myimages">
       <span><a><img src="image1.png" alt="image1"></a></span>
       <span><a><img src="image2.png" alt="image2"></a></span>
       <span><a><img src="image3.png" alt="image3"></a></span>
       <span><a><img src="image4.png" alt="image4"></a></span>
       <span><a><img src="image5.png" alt="image5"></a></span>
    </div>
```

When I click on the image I want to get the attribute of the image that is clicked. How to get the attribute of the image that has been clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .attr() method.

```
$('.myimages a').click(function(){
   alert($(this).children("img").attr('alt'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zsz7p/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your click is on the `<a>` tag, use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$("a").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).find("img").prop("alt"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look

```
         $(document).on('click','.myimages a',function(e){

             alert($(this).find('img').prop('src'));

          });
```